# How to create an NSArray of times with 5mins interval between objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am stuck trying to get an array of time fetched from a website. I got the array which happens to be this one:

```
NSArray *rawData = @[@"8:06", @"8:07", @"8:08", @"8:09", @"8:10", @"8:11", @"8:12", @"8:13",@"8:14", @"8:15", @"8:16", @"8:17", @"8:18", @"8:19", @"8:20", .... @"15:05"];
```

So the array goes from 8:06 up to 15:05 in 1min increments. What I want I just can't figure out how to do, is a new array from that one but starting with the first 5 multiple time, i.e: 8:10 and the go on incrementing by 5 mins up to 15:05, so that the NSLog of the final array would be like this:

```
8:10, 8:15, 8:20, 8:25, ...., 10:45, 10:50, 10:55, 11:00, 11:05, ...., 14:55, 15:00, 15:05
```

So any ideas???

Comment: `-[NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:]` looks like what you need: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/dateByAddingTimeInterval:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case you could just check if the time string ends with "0" or "5":

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '0' OR SELF ENDSWITH '5'"];
NSArray *filteredData = [rawData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

(Note that this is a special solution for multiples of 5. You could proceed similarly for
multiples of 10, but it would not work in other cases like multiples of 3 or 7.)

Comment: @user1673099: 21, 12, 03, 24, 15, 06, 27, 18, 09, 30 are all multiples of 3. So you cannot see from the last digit if a number is a multiple of 3.

Comment: @MartinR, thanks for your explaination but what are the other options for that?

Comment: @user1673099: you have to convert the strings to integers and then check each number if it divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

One more way you can try like this below:-

```
NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"8.01",@"8.05",@"8.06",@"8.10",@"8.02",nil];
NSMutableArray *arrMut=[NSMutableArray array];
for(NSString *str in arr)
{
    if ([str length]>3)
    {
    NSString *str1=[str substringFromIndex:3];
    if ([str1 intValue]==5 || [str1 intValue]==0)
        [arrMut addObject:str];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",arrMut);
```